# calculate difference between rows for the same product

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, difference

I am using Python and Pandas to make some calculations over a dataframe that contains millions of rows like the following ones:

```
city    product     month       sold
Milan   Spaghetti   2021-03-31  30300
Milan   Spaghetti   2021-06-30  26958
Milan   Spaghetti   2021-09-30  26775
Milan   Spaghetti   2021-12-31  44185
Milan   Spaghetti   2022-03-31  32716
Milan   Spaghetti   2022-06-30  25881
Milan   Maccheroni  2021-03-31  89584
Milan   Maccheroni  2021-06-30  81434
Milan   Maccheroni  2021-09-30  83360
Milan   Maccheroni  2021-12-31  123945
Milan   Maccheroni  2022-03-31  97278
Milan   Maccheroni  2022-06-30  82959
Rome    Spaghetti   2021-01-31  1524
Rome    Spaghetti   2021-04-30  1548
Rome    Spaghetti   2021-07-31  1577
Rome    Spaghetti   2021-10-31  1438
Rome    Spaghetti   2022-01-31  1556
Rome    Spaghetti   2022-04-30  1471
Rome    Spaghetti   2022-07-31  1453
Rome    Maccheroni  2021-01-31  15646
Rome    Maccheroni  2021-04-30  15877
Rome    Maccheroni  2021-07-31  15289
Rome    Maccheroni  2021-10-31  16675
Rome    Maccheroni  2022-01-31  17028
Rome    Maccheroni  2022-04-30  16490
Rome    Maccheroni  2022-07-31  14664
```

I am looking for a way to calculate the changes between subsequent months for the same city and product, so that the resulting dataframe is like that:

```
city    product     month       sold    change
Milan   Spaghetti   31/03/2021  30300   
Milan   Spaghetti   30/06/2021  26958   -3342
Milan   Spaghetti   30/09/2021  26775   -183
Milan   Spaghetti   31/12/2021  44185   17410
Milan   Spaghetti   31/03/2022  32716   -11469
Milan   Spaghetti   30/06/2022  25881   -6835
Milan   Maccheroni  31/03/2021  89584   
Milan   Maccheroni  30/06/2021  81434   -8150
Milan   Maccheroni  30/09/2021  83360   1926
Milan   Maccheroni  31/12/2021  123945  40585
Milan   Maccheroni  31/03/2022  97278   -26667
Milan   Maccheroni  30/06/2022  82959   -14319
Rome    Spaghetti   31/01/2021  1524    
Rome    Spaghetti   30/04/2021  1548    24
Rome    Spaghetti   31/07/2021  1577    29
Rome    Spaghetti   31/10/2021  1438    -139
Rome    Spaghetti   31/01/2022  1556    118
Rome    Spaghetti   30/04/2022  1471    -85
Rome    Spaghetti   31/07/2022  1453    -18
Rome    Maccheroni  31/01/2021  15646   
Rome    Maccheroni  30/04/2021  15877   231
Rome    Maccheroni  31/07/2021  15289   -588
Rome    Maccheroni  31/10/2021  16675   1386
Rome    Maccheroni  31/01/2022  17028   353
Rome    Maccheroni  30/04/2022  16490   -538
Rome    Maccheroni  31/07/2022  14664   -1826
```

The code shod calculate the change between two rows only if the city and product field are the same. Is it possible to do it without iterating on the rows ?

**Please** ignore the change in the month format, it is irrelevant for the solution.

Comment: `df['change'] = df.groupby(['city','product'])['sold'].diff()`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

```
difference_df = (df
 .assign(difference=lambda x: x.groupby(['city', 'product'])['sold'].transform(lambda x: x.diff()))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to vectorize this with the `shift` function. You just have to make sure you:

1. Sort by categories, date in that order (which it looks like you have)
2. Mark as `NaN` the first month for every category after the fact.

The code would look something like this:

```
category_cols = ["city", "product"]
df = df.sort_values(category_cols + ["month"])

# Get difference
df["change"] = df.sold - df.sold.shift(1)

# Get new categories, mark missing
new_cat_mask = (df[category_cols] != df[category_cols].shift(1)).any(axis=1)
df.loc[new_cat_mask, "change"] = np.nan
```